# Is this a correct way to get a random number between 1024 and 65535?

Tags: php, random

```
unpack('n', random_bytes(2))[1] % 64512 + 1024;
```

I believe `random_bytes(2)` returns a binary between 0-65535, `unpack('n')` creates a decimal out of it, the reminder after dividing by 64512 is between 0-64511, adding 1024 results in 1024-65535. Anything I missed? (And no, `mt_rand(1024, 655535)` is not adequate for the purpose.)

Comment: Would [`random_int(1024,65535)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) do?

Comment: @FlashThunder Phil already asked that. I'm guessing it's because it's not cryptographically secure like `random_bytes()`.\

Comment: But `random_int — Generates cryptographically secure pseudo-random integers`

Comment: When you say "`mt_rand(1024, 655535)` is not adequate for the purpose", you have to say why, or any suggestion we might propose could have the same issue. As to your question, your method makes numbers from `1024` to `2047` twice as probable as other numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is not very good, because it will bias the random numbers.

```
unpack('n', random_bytes(2))[1]
```

will return a random number between `0` and `65535`. The modulus will leave all the numbers from `0` to `64512` the same, and shift `64513-65535` down to `0-1023`. Then you add `1024` to this.

The result will be that you're more likely to get `1024-2047` than other numbers in the range.

You need to use a method that contracts the range rather than combining numbers. The function `random_int(1024, 65535)` should do this correctly. It uses the same random number generator as `random_bytes()`.